# Undocumented ModR/M byte combinations

Tags: assembly, 8086, undocumented-opcodes

The reason I am asking this question is because I was trying to compile a list of all 8086 opcodes, regardless of whether or not they are documented. The list is just for fun, the documented opcodes + the well known undocumented ones such as `SALC` are more than enough for any serious code designed for the 8086.

There is quite a lot of documentation online on single-byte undocumented instructions of the 8086/88, such as `SALC (D6)` or `POP CS (0F)`, but there seems to be little info on undocumented/invalid multi-byte opcodes. The 8086 doesn't have an invalid opcode exception, so every opcode combination must necessarily do something.

Let's take an interesting instruction, for example: `LEA`. This instruction computes a memory address using regular addressing modes (`BX + SI`, `BP + DI + disp` etc.) and stores that address in a general-purpose register. All instructions that compute addresses this way use a ModR/M byte that follows the instruction opcode (in this case `8D`).

The ModR/M byte has the format `xxrrrmmm`, where `xx` is the mode, `mmm` is the memory/register operand, while `rrr` is the other register operand (notice how the 8086 never uses 2 memory operands in the same instruction). The mode defines the kind of memory/register operand: `00`, `01`, `10` are different types of memory operands, while `11` is a register operand.

If we assemble `LEA DX, [BP + DI]`, we get `8D 11`. The ModR/M byte is `0x11`, or `00 010 001`. The `rrr`=`010`, which means that the destination register is `DX`. The `xx`=`00`, so we have a memory operand without a displacement. Finally, the `mmm`=`001`, which stands for `BP + DI`.

The manual doesn't specify what happens when you use mode `xx`=`11` (both operands are registers). For example, a ModR/M byte `11 010 001` would make the instruction `LEA DX, CX`, which doesn't make much sense. The question is what does the 8086 do when it encounters such weird combinations in the ModR/M byte?

`LEA` is not the only instruction that has invalid combinations of ModR/M. There are also some instructions which don't use the `rrr` field at all, because the second operand is an immediate value (or because there is no second operand). In such cases, the manual says that the `rrr` field must be `000`.

There are also "group" instructions. Instructions that are part of a group (such as shift, rotate, multiply, divide etc.) use the same opcode for the first byte, but never use the `rrr` field. To distinguish between instructions, the `rrr` field is the index of the instruction in the group, and the ModR/M byte is usually written as `/i`, with `i` being from `0` to `7` and representing the `rrr` field. For example, `D2 /0` means `ROL r/m8, CL`, while `D2 /1` means `ROR r/m8, CL`. Some of these indexes, however, are not assigned to any instruction, for example `GRP3 /1` and most of GRP4, and are therefore undefined.

Here is a list of instructions that can have an illegal ModR/M byte (it aims to be exhaustive, but probably isn't):

- Instructions that by design can only take a memory operand (`xx`=`11` is not documented by the manual):

  - `8D`: `LEA r16, addr` (technically it's not `m16` because it doesn't access memory)
  - `C4`: `LES r16, m16:16`
  - `C5`: `LDS r16, m16:16`
- Instructions that have only one non-immediate operand (the `rrr` field is unused and the manual says it should always be `000`, almost as if they were group instructions with index `/0`):

  - `8F`: `POP r/m16`
  - `C6`: `MOV r/m8, imm8`
  - `C7`: `MOV r/m16, imm16`
- "Group" instructions with an undocumented index in the `rrr` field:

  - `GRP2 /6` ([this list of undocumented opcodes](https://www.os2museum.com/wp/undocumented-8086-opcodes-part-i/) says it is a "set −1" instruction, but on a modern x86 CPU it executes as `SHL`/`SAL`, which is more plausible, since this is where `SAL` would be if it wasn't an alias for `SHL`)
  - `GRP3 /1`
  - `GRP4 /2~7` (this group only has 2 documented instructions, `INC` and `DEC`)
  - `GRP5 /7`

Comment: I imagine you’re aware of [this list of undocumented opcodes](https://www.os2museum.com/wp/undocumented-8086-opcodes-part-i/) (but it’s mostly single-byte opcodes). There’s also [this brief analysis of the microcode](https://www.reenigne.org/blog/8086-microcode-disassembled/). None of these address your question!

Comment: Except for LEA, I would expect most of those opcodes would simply be interpreted as two-byte ways of performing operations that can also be done with a single byte form.  Not sure what LEA would do, though.

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes, I am aware of those. The first one is probably the most interesting, since it claims to be Part I, while Parts II and III (which were never posted) have titles that could answer this question and many others.

Comment: @supercat For LES and LDS it's the same problem as with LEA. For the versions of POP and MOV that I mentioned, [this](http://www.mlsite.net/8086/) claims that the `rrr` field must be 0 or the opcode is illegal. I suspect the CPU ignores it, but there may be some interesting quirk which affects the selected register (for example setting `rrr`=`001` would select CX), like clobbering it or something if `rrr` is not 0, so this is why I added them on the list.

Comment: @DarkAtom yup, Parts II and III were what sprung to my mind when I saw your question; [see this comment at the bottom of Part I](https://www.os2museum.com/wp/undocumented-8086-opcodes-part-i/#comment-363679).

Comment: @DarkAtom: Ah, that makes sense.  It might be useful to flesh out your list of what aspects of R/M are restricted for which instructions.  I wonder why Intel would have three separate leading opcode bytes that are limited to 32 or fewer meaningful second-byte values each, especially when there are gaps in groups 3a, 3b, and 5 which would have seemed a natural fit for those instructions, since 3a and 3b each already have an instruction that takes immediate byte or word operand, and 5 includes "push".

Comment: @supercat I extended the list to include the group instructions and also specified how each instruction has undefined ModR/M combinations as you suggested. I suppose the key to the answer is probably the microcode, which for the 8086/88 was thankfully disassembled already. But for that one would probably have to spend quite a few hours of analysis.

Comment: On modern computers, `LES` and `LDS` with `mod == 11` are `VEX` prefixes encoding AVX instructions.  Not that this would be relevant to the 8086 in any way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As part of his series about the 8086 micro code Ken Shirriff has just added a blog post where he analyses some of the mentioned cases:

**[Undocumented 8086 instructions, explained by the microcode](https://www.righto.com/2023/07/undocumented-8086-instructions.html)**

It explains for example

- LEA reg,reg loads a value from an internal register called IND, which in normal cases would be filled with whatever the EA calculation yields - except, when ModR/M points to a register no EA calculation is done. As a result giving access to previous IND.
- LES/LDS will act similar, except two internal registers OPR and IND are used. EA handling would have loaded the effective address into IND and loaded OPR from that address. LES/DS would now load OPR into the target register, increment IND by two and load the segment register with the word pointed to by IND. As a result OPR can be accessed, while destroying the segment register.
- JMP FAR with a register would act likewise, except now loading an internal tmpB into PC and whatever IND+2 points to into CS - thus giving (hard to use) access to tmpB.

Register meaning

- Indirect (IND) holds an address within a segment (16 bit offset)
- Operand (OPR) holds the data value read or written
- tmpB holds the second operand of any ALU operation

For more see the [blog entry](https://www.righto.com/2023/07/undocumented-8086-instructions.html) - although, the C6/C7 group is not covered.